# KMM library build failed with e: Could not find

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

When building a Kotlin Multiplatform library, using CocoaPods as explained here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-cocoapods.html

you may encounter the following errors:

```
Execution failed for task ':shared:linkPodDebugFrameworkIosArm64'.
...
Execution failed for task ':shared:linkPodDebugFrameworkIosX64'.
...
Execution failed for task ':shared:linkPodDebugFrameworkIosSimulatorArm64'.
...
Execution failed for task ':shared:linkPodReleaseFrameworkIosArm64'.
...
Execution failed for task ':shared:linkPodReleaseFrameworkIosX64'.
...
Execution failed for task ':shared:linkPodReleaseFrameworkIosSimulatorArm64'.
...

e: Could not find 'My' in [...]
```

What can be the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible cause for this is having a white space in the Gradle project name:

In `settings.gradle.kts`:

```
rootProject.name = "My App"
```

Replace it with:

```
rootProject.name = "My_App"
```